# Read Only Table displays foreign key instead of details

Tags: oracle-adf

**Summarize the problem**

So I have a Department Table which has a column Location ID which references a Location Table.

FYI: (Department.locationID = Location.LocationID)

Now on my UI page when I drag and drop the department collection to make a table it displays the locationID instead of the location name. My end users won't understand Location ID, they'll need to see the locationName.

**Provide background including what you've already tried**

On my Department VO, I have referenced the locationID to a LOV so that it displays the LocationName. When the table is updatable, I have no issues, but when the table is read only the ID is being displayed instead of name.

I have read few blogs where they suggest to make the table column SelectOneChoice. Find the code snippet taken from my jsf page below.

**Show some code**

```
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.Departments1.hints.DepartmentLocationId.label}" id="c6">

   <af:selectOneChoice value="#{row.DepartmentLocationId}"
      shortDesc="#{bindings.Departments1.hints.DepartmentId.tooltip}"
      id="soc1" readOnly="true">
      <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Departments1.hints.DepartmentLocationId.format}"/>
   </af:selectOneChoice>

   <!-- <af:outputText value="#{row.DepartmentLocationId}"
      shortDesc="#{bindings.Departments1.hints.DepartmentLocationId.tooltip}" id="ot6">
      <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Departments1.hints.DepartmentLocationId.format}"/>
      </af:outputText> -->

</af:column>
```

**Describe expected and actual results including any error messages**

After making the above changes (I commented out "**outputText**" section and added the "**selectOneChoice**" section) my location column doesn't display anything.

My expected output is for the table to display Location Name and not locationID.

I'm using JDeveloper 12c.

Answer (score 0):

So just in case, anyone else faces the same issue, here is what I did as a workaround. It's not the exact solution to the above problem, but it works.

Instead of relying on VO based on one EO, I made a VO that's based on two EOs. the DepartmentEO and LocationEO. In the VO layer, **both EOs should also be related with an association.**

Now my DepartmentVO has an extra attribute called LocationName. On the UI front, I hide my LocationID and instead display the LocationName.

Comment: So you just rewrited the unacepted answer i gave you on your other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588685/search-ui-on-employee-table-with-the-department-name-and-not-department-id

Comment: @Cedric Acknowledged.